# Printing Grid Control with multiple elements

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to print a grid control with multiple elements in it.

I am doing this,

```
PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog();
if (printDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
{
    printDialog.PrintVisual(gridReport, "Visit Report");                    
}
```

gridReport is my grid name.
As my grid contains a lot of child elements, only a part of it is getting printed and rest is getting chopped.

How should i solve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem a month ago. As far as i know .Net print dialog only prints one page and cuts everything beyond that page. If you want to print multi pages you have to write some logic yourself.

I created a bmp file and cut it to multiple pages, added the pages to a list and at the end printed the list of pages.

I found this article very helpful (it has a solution that cuts the bmpwhenever the height of one page is exceeded, so you will also have to implement a similar logic to cut your bmp when the width of a page is exceeded)

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/339416/Printing-large-WPF-UserControls

i hope this will help.